# "In the roads" vs. "on the roads"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, in-on

> - He is driving in the roads of the mountain.
> - He is driving on the roads of the mountain.

Which is correct, "in the roads" or "on the roads"?

Comment: *On* the roads. But we'd probably say *driving the mountain roads* (if a specific mountain is involved) or *driving mountain roads* (if not).

Comment: [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest)!

Answer (score 0):

You drive **on** roads because you are on a road - never inside it.

However you can drive **in** a region - so you might drive **on** a road **in** the mountains.

Comment: You can drive *in* the road just fine, but only [until you get to the cow](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lyorl.png).