# Is a building said to be along the road or on the road?

Tags: prepositions

In my country (Zambia) I hear adverts saying, "Our offices are along X Road". Is this correct? Should it not be on X Road? Along implies motion, like "driving along the road". unless the buildig covers the entire stretch of the road, like trees (There are trees along X Road).

Comment: I guess it depends how long the building is ;)

Comment: Usually *along* is used with some kind of verb of action, as in "arrayed along X Road" or "sprawled along X Road"—but there is nothing awkward about saying "Our offices are along X Road." This usage suggests a line of buildings, though, as opposed to a single location.

Comment: Related to: (1) [ON an American street, but IN a British one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54251/on-an-american-street-but-in-a-british-one-do-the-twain-ever-meet/118623#118623), and (2) [“In the roads” vs. “on the roads”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112717/in-the-roads-vs-on-the-roads)

Comment: I'm not sure where to add this comment, but I think it needs posting. Unless I've mis-checked twice, the preposition 'along', which is cited in the OP, is not addressed at all in the 'duplicates'.

Comment: Did you notice the plural? Perhaps the reference is to several offices stretching, yes, "along" the road X? That's the likelier explanation. In any case, Edwin Ashworth's answer too holds good.

Comment: The purported "duplicate" notwithstanding, this Q has merit of its own. However, this Q. suffered closure not because it is a duplicate at all but for a lack of research. 1. Does not show background effort. 2. Does not show that previous questions have been checked out.

Answer (score 2):

**Along** is used in several overlapping ways. The directed locative sense used here can be found on Google:

> The long-stay car park is a little way along the road towards
>   Dartmouth.

However, I don't think that the usual online dictionaries mention this sense. Notice that it is a deictic sense - along from (or towards) where? (Usually from where the speaker is standing, or pointing to on the map.) It is an alternative to *up* or *down* (the road etc) when these are appropriate. *On* or *in* George Street say is not deictic, merely locative.